# What do operations n % 2 == 1 and n //= 2 do in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, modulo, floor-division

Can someone explain the semantics of

```
n % 2 == 1
```

and

```
n //= 2
```

As I understood `n % 2 == 1` checks if the remainder of the division of `n` by `2` is `1`.

What about `n //= 2`? Is this a floor division? But of what? `n` divided by `2`?

Comment: The second one is [*augmented assignment*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=augmented#object.__iadd__), basically `n = n // 2`.

Comment: I think you can try it in IDE online python console you will get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n % 2 == 1` means to return `True` if the remainder of `n / 2` equals to one, the same as checking if `n` is an odd number.

So if `n` equals to `6`, the above expression will return `False`. If `n` equals to `9`, it will return `True`.

`n //= 2` means to redefine the `n` variable, but assigning the original value with the floor division of `2` calculated into it.

So if `n` equals to `6`, the above expression will change its value to `3`. If `n` equals to `9`, it will change its value to `4`.